# Update Textbox value which are in loop using Post Submit (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have 2 textbox in loop
and i want to update their value in database when i press button.

the issue is that when i press button it updates only last textbox value .

**following is my model.**

```
function approvedHrs($taskid,$data)
{
    //$this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->where('taskid', $taskid);
     $this->db->update(MILESTONE, $data);
}
```

**Following is my View (For lop is here)**

```
<?php
foreach ($result as $milestone_row) {   
?>
<tr id="<?php echo $milestone_row->id; ?>"> 
    <?php
    if ($is_master_admin) {
        if ($i > 1) {
            if ($milestone_row->userid == $userid) {
            } else {
                $userid = $milestone_row->userid;
                echo $milestone_row->usertitle;
            }
        } else {
            $userid = $milestone_row->userid;
            echo $milestone_row->usertitle;
        }
    }
    ?>
<li class="in">
    <a href="">Add Bug</a>
    <div class="message">
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        <span class="body">
            <?php
            echo '<b> <U> Task Title </U>:- </b> &nbsp';
            echo $milestone_row->tasktitle;
            echo '<br/>';
            echo '<b> <U> Workspace Title </U>:- </b> &nbsp';
            echo $milestone_row->workspacetitle;
            echo '<br/>';
            echo '<b> <U> Description </U>:- </b> &nbsp';
            echo $milestone_row->description;
            echo '<br/>';
            echo '<b> <U> Hours </U>:- </b> &nbsp';
            echo $milestone_row->esthours;
            echo 'hrs';
            echo '<br/>';
            echo '<b> <U> Minutes </U>:- </b> &nbsp';
            echo $milestone_row->estmin;
            echo'mins';
            echo '<br/>';
            ?>
            <b><u>Approved Hours:-</u></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

<input style="height:14px;font-size:10pt; width: 33px" type="text" id="hours" name="approvedhrs" data-required="1"  value="<?php echo $milestone_row->esthours; ?>" placeholder="Hours" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />

<input style="height:14px;font-size:10pt; width: 33px" type="text" id="minutes" name="approvedmins" value="<?php echo $milestone_row->estmin; ?>" data-required="1" placeholder="Minutes" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"  />

            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>milestone/editMilestone/<?php echo $milestone_row->id;?>/<?php echo $milestone_row->taskid;?>">Edit</a>
            <?php echo " | ";?>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>milestone/deleteMilestone/<?php echo $milestone_row->id;?>/<?php echo $milestone_row->taskid;?>">Delete</a>
            <!--<span class="datetime">at <?php //echo $milestone_row->createddate; ?></span> -->
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Followinf is myController**

```
function approvedHrs($taskid)
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){       
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $id = $session_data['id'];
            $username = $session_data['username'];
            $is_master_admin = $session_data['master'];
            $imagethumb = $session_data['imagethumb'];
            $pendingbug = $this->bugmodel->getBug($id, $is_master_admin);
            $pendingtask = $this->taskmodel->getTask($id, $is_master_admin);

            $data = '';
                $data = array(
                    'approvedhrs' =>$this->input->post('approvedhrs'),
                    'approvedmins'=>$this->input->post('approvedmins')
                );
//                print_r($data);
//                exit;
                $result = $this->milestonemodel->approvedHrs($taskid,$data);
//              $this->session->set_userdata('msg', $result);
                redirect('task', 'refresh');
      }
      else 
      {
              redirect('login', 'refresh');
      }
    }
```

When i use array like this  it gives me following error

PHP Error Occured :Message: Array to string conversion

Database Error : Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
UPDATE `milestone` SET `approvedhrs` = Array, `approvedmins` = Array WHERE `taskid` = '17'

Comment: This will get you started [link](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/deleting-multiple-records-with-php/)...Yeah because on server side php controller you need to accept it as array, loop through it to insert the data.

Comment: The above link is for deleting, but you will understand how to do it for insert too using that...

Comment: @siddharth Can you plz give me example of Codeigniter??

Comment: 'approvedhrs' =>$this->input->post('approvedhrs'), gets the array from the client. so it is giving that error.

Comment: ok i will have to search it and return back

Comment: where is your form to post? How are you posting?

Comment: @siddharth yes may be erro is here 'approvedhrs' =>$this->input->post('approvedhrs'),
what should i change here.
hope u will rpl me soon

Comment: @raheelshan i am posting using button which is not I display here because whole code is too much long

Comment: How are you posting i mean using ajax or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simplify your code like this

```
$post   =   $this->input->post();               

$data['approvedhrs']    =   $post['approvedhrs'];
$data['approvedmins']   =   $post['approvedmins'];

print_r($data);

$result = $this->milestonemodel->approvedHrs($taskid,$data);
```

You should make sure `$post['approvedhrs']` and `$post['approvedmins']` do not have arrays. They could contain array when defined in the form like this

```
<input type='text' name="approvedhrs[]" />
<input type='text' name="approvedmins[]" />
```

EDIT

As you are making inputs inside loops there fore both `approvedhrs` and `approvedmins` are posted as array. Which is causing problem in updating.

EDIT

You should make the inputs in your loop like this

```
<input type='text' name="approvedhrs[]" />
<input type='text' name="approvedmins[]" />
```

Make hidden inputs for row id and task id

```
<input type='hidden' name="rowid[]" />
<input type='hidden' name="taskid[]" />
<input type='text' name="approvedhrs[]" />
<input type='text' name="approvedmins[]" />
```

And now php

```
$post  =   $this->input->post();              

$data['approvedhrs']   =   $post['approvedhrs'];
$data['approvedmins']  =   $post['approvedmins'];

for($i=0;$i<count($data['approvedhrs']);$i++){

    $update_data['approvedhrs']     =   $data['approvedhrs'][$i];
    $update_data['approvedmins']    =   $data['approvedmins'][$i];
    $taskid                         =   $data['taskid'][$i];
    print_r($update_data);
    $result = $this->milestonemodel->approvedHrs($taskid,$update_data);
    unset($update_data);
    unset($taskid);
}
```

Comment: Still it gives me same error
A PHP Error was encountered:Message: Array to string conversion

A Database Error Occurred:
Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
UPDATE `milestone` SET `approvedhrs` = Array, `approvedmins` = Array WHERE `taskid` = '17'

Comment: put you ajax code how you are posting data without it nothing can solve this problem

Comment: Simply i used
<?php                                                                        echo form_open('milestone/approvedHrs/'. $result[0]->taskid ););
                                    ?>

Comment: I am not using ajax anywhere in my project

Comment: are you making inputs inside loop? This means there are two inputs on each row?

Comment: yes correct i m making inputs inside loops.
there are two inputs on each row

Comment: so the form is posting it as array because there are too many input boxes with same name

Comment: Yes exactly there you are...
and every row has there unique id..
so entry should be update on that particular row id and task id

Comment: the problem is that it is always overwriting let me edit the answer

Comment: Now what should i do for proper output??

Comment: are you sure you have seen the updates. That's because of task id i updated the answer please take a look again

Comment: undefined index: taskid

Comment: it will surely be undefined when you dont define it in your html form

Comment: Change <input type='hidden' name="taskid[]" /> to <input type='hidden' name="approvedhrs[taskid][]" />

Comment: One thing you are forgetting. You should always give value to hidden input liek this `<input type='hidden' name ='taskid[]' value ='<?php echo $id?>'>`. Where `$id` should be current row id in the loop

Comment: without providing id php will always say no id found because we did not give any on html end

Comment: @SKG i am in company now here no Dropbox facility

Comment: @SKG if posible can u give me ur emailid ?

Comment: @Ritesh please take a look deeply at your code you must be making some mistake somewhere. Try googling this problem and you will know the process how you can achieve this task

Comment: if someone else does your work this will not increase your abilities and skills

Comment: @Ritesh please take a look deeply at your code you must be making some mistake somewhere. Try googling this problem and you will know the process how you can achieve this task

Comment: @Ritesh I am also in company I cannot send my company's email ID with you and can't use personal . So solution is goto [link](http://ideone.com) paste your whole controller and rus then you will get redirect to a link then . Post that link here. Do it for model and view page also

Comment: @raheelshan i also feel that i took mistake somewhere but i coudn't found where it is actually

Comment: @Ritesh post your whole controller , model and view page

Comment: @raheelshan
i got my Array
(
    [approvedhrs] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
        )

    [approvedmins] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

)
in my original code

means i got all values in array now what should i do next??

Comment: @SKG I uploaded Whole Model,View , Cotroller at yyour given link

Controller :- http://ideone.com/tBb7mx
Model :- http://ideone.com/8cTJRp
View :- http://ideone.com/Y3XdO4

Comment: @Ritesh can you plz provide your task and milestone tbl structure

Comment: @Ritesh I think you have two table task and milestote , In Task table taskid is PK and in milestote milestoteid is PK and taskid is FK. So why update table milestote using taskid(FK) ?? use milestoteid(PK)

Comment: @SKG Yes you r right In Task table taskid is PK and in milestote milestoteid is PK and taskid is FK.

Now what to do tell me

Comment: @SKG i think there is somthing wrong i nmycontroller..can u check my controller is it right??

is there any for loop required??

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing array of data to update, you can use update_batch mentod.

In your controller, prepare the data as below.

```
$k= 0 ;
$data = array();
$aphrs = $this->input->post('approvedhrs'); // returns array
$apmis = $this->input->post('approvedmins'); // 
foreach($aphrs  as $hrs)
{
   $data[] = array(
                    'approvedhrs' =>$hrs,
                    'approvedmins'=>$apmis[$k]
                );
   $k++;
}
```

// call your model function

```
$result = $this->milestonemodel->approvedHrs($taskid,$data);
```

In your model function: add update_batch method. So no need to call update method in forloop.

for update_batch, check this tutorial.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update

Answer (score 0):

## View

```
<input type='hidden' name="milestoneid[]" value ="<?php echo $milestone_row->id ?>" />
<input  type="text" id="hours" name="approvedhrs[<?php echo $milestone_row->id ?>][]"  value="<?php echo $milestone_row->esthours; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="approvedmins[<?php echo $milestone_row->id ?>][]" value="<?php   echo $milestone_row->estmin; ?>"/>
```

## Controller

```
function approvedHrs($taskid) {
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
                $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                $id = $session_data['id'];
                $username = $session_data['username'];
                $is_master_admin = $session_data['master'];
                $imagethumb = $session_data['imagethumb'];
                $pendingbug = $this->bugmodel->getBug($id, $is_master_admin);
                $pendingtask = $this->taskmodel->getTask($id, $is_master_admin);
                $data = array();

                $milestoneIDs = $this->input->post('milestoneid');
                $approvedhrs = $this->input->post('approvedhrs');
                $approvedmins = $this->input->post('approvedmins');

                foreach ($milestoneIDs as $milestoneID) {
                        $data = array(
                                    'approvedhrs' => isset($approvedhrs[$milestoneID]) ? $approvedhrs[$milestoneID] : '',
                                    'approvedmins' => isset($approvedmins[$milestoneID]) ? $approvedmins[$milestoneID] : '',
                        );
                        $this->milestone_model->approvedHrs($milestoneID,$data);//change this model name as per you use
                        unset($data);
                }

                redirect('task', 'refresh');
        } else {
                redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }
}
```

## Model

```
function approvedHrs($milestoteid, $data) {
//$this->db->where('id', $editid);
        $this->db->where('milestoteid', $milestoteid);
        $this->db->update(MILESTONE, $data);
}
```